# Deploy LWC component of Unlocked package with namespace from vs code

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, unlocked-package

We have installed the unlocked package(with namespace) into the org.

We are trying to deploy the LWC component through VS code, which is a part of the unlocked package(with namespace). Instead of updating the existing component, it creates a new component in the org. Is there any way, we can update the existing the unlocked package component on the subscriber org?

Comment: Did you set the namespace in sfdx-project.json? I suspect this is the reason why you're creating new components instead of updating the unlocked package version. Ordinarily, you wouldn't do updates like this, however, you'd build a new Unlocked Package version and install.

Comment: @sfdcfox Even after including the namespace in the sfdx-project.json file, it creates the new component. Currently, the package up-gradation is failing because of the following reason: 1. We have deleted one class from the unlocked version.We have one LWC component that calls the same component.

Comment: This problem is still relevant